# Variable is not reading from .env file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this file here `.env` varible is showing `undefined` . How to overcome this error?

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('./models/user');
const routes = require('./routes.js');
const url = '*************************************'; // MongoDB server URL
const databaseName = 'Blocks'; // Name of the database
const collectionName = 'admin'; // Name of the collection

require("dotenv").config({
  path: path.join(__dirname, "./")
});



const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect(`${url}/${databaseName}`, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully');
    
    // Access the desired collection
    const collection = mongoose.connection.collection(collectionName);
    
    // Perform operations on the collection
    // For example, insert a document
    const document = { name: 'John', age: 30 };
    collection.insertOne(document)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('Inserted document ID:', result.insertedId);
        
        // Close the connection
        mongoose.connection.close();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Failed to insert document:', err);
        mongoose.connection.close();
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB:', err);
  });

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers["x-access-token"]) {
    const accessToken = req.headers["x-access-token"];
    const { userId, exp } = await jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    // Check if token has expired
    if (exp < Date.now().valueOf() / 1000) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "JWT token has expired, please login to obtain a new one" });
    }
    res.locals.loggedInUser = await User.findById(userId);
    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on Port:', PORT);
});
```

When I run this, getting `undefined`

`console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET);`

Comment: According documentation it should be `path: path.join(__dirname, ".env")` or just try `require("dotenv").config()`. If it does not work, use `require('dotenv').config({ debug: true })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in index.js file

```
require("dotenv").config()
```

in .env file without space

```
JWT_SECRET=keiEKjfdk3fe3fds
```

if you are using symbols in jwt_secret try using Single Quote ('') or backtick(``)

```
JWT_SECRET='keiEKjfdk3fe3fds=#k3fdEEE'
```

Comment: if the remove the PATH i am getting client is not running error